# Excel VBA auto updating form images with dynamic filepath via excel power query

Tags: excel, vba

Short explanation what will be the target of the program.  I have 3 Optical sensors, 3 images will be send in folder via an FTP-server. I have an power query in excel that updates every 1 second and is filtered so the latest pictures are shown above, this path is used to link this with the form.

Now I want the last 3 pictures of that specific folder shown in a form. At this moment the following works (up-to-date):

- Auto update powerquery (needed a checkbox to stop the refresh of the file)
- Start button that alows the first 3 pictures that are the latest

What is not working:
**- Auto updating the images in the form when new pictures arrive from FTP-server. How can I show last pictures all the time in the VBA form? Without pressing any button**

This is the code:

```
Private Sub StartBtn_Click()

Image1.picture = LoadPicture("C:\Users\svanheme\Desktop\" & Range("A2").Value)
Image2.picture = LoadPicture("C:\Users\svanheme\Desktop\" & Range("A3").Value)
Image3.picture = LoadPicture("C:\Users\svanheme\Desktop\" & Range("A4").Value)
    UserForm1.CheckBox1.Value = True
    Call Calculate_Range

End Sub

Private Sub StopBtn_Click()

 UserForm1.CheckBox1.Value = False
End Sub


Public Sub Calculate_Range()
       
       
    If (UserForm1.CheckBox1.Value = True) Then

        ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
        Range("H2:H6").Calculate
      
        'IF I DO THIS IT GIVES AN ERROR AND I DONT KNOW WHY THIS IS.
        'Image1.picture = LoadPicture("C:\Users\svanheme\Desktop\" & Range("A2").Value)
        'Image2.picture = LoadPicture("C:\Users\svanheme\Desktop\" & Range("A3").Value)
        'Image3.picture = LoadPicture("C:\Users\svanheme\Desktop\" & Range("A4").Value)

        Application.OnTime DateAdd("s", 1, Now), "Calculate_Range"
End If
 
    If (UserForm1.CheckBox1.Value = False) Then
  
        
End If

End Sub
```

Would be great if someone could advice me.

Kind regards,

Sander

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to make your form modeless and update the pictures when powerquery updates (or run it every second or two). I am not an expert in pwerquery and therefore, do not know how to capture the event of pwerquery updating - I doubt it will trigger a Worksheet_Change (but I could be wrong)

Comment: Hi Super Symmetry, the problem is that the image doesn't auto-update when the path changes. Who u suggest another way to approach?

Comment: I totally understand your problem. Did you understand my point about making the form modeless? and updating the image when either powerquery updates or the path changes?

Comment: Hi Super Symmetry, I did this and it worked, thank you very much.